# Type mismatch when using object mapping and rest operator in return statement

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a TypeScript project with Prisma and I'm facing a type mismatch error when trying to return an object with mapped properties in the `getPool` method.

Here's the relevant code:

```
public async getPool({ id, voterId }: { id: string; voterId: string }): Promise<{ pool: getPoolResult }> {
   const pool = await prisma.pool.findFirst({
      where: { id },
      include: { answers: { include: { votes: true } } },
   })

   // ...

   return {
      pool: {
         ...this.poolMapper.map(pool),
         voteCounts,
         votedAnswerId: votedAnswerId as string | null,
      },
   }
}
```

And here are my types:

```
export const PoolSchema = z.object({
   id: z.string(),
   question: z.string().min(MIN_QUESTION_LENGTH).max(MAX_QUESTION_LENGTH),
   expiresAt: z.coerce.date(),
   answers: z.array(
      z.object({
         id: z.string(),
         value: z.string(),
      })
   ),
   isPublic: z.boolean(),
   password: z.string().optional(),
})

export type PoolData = z.infer<typeof PoolSchema>

export type VoteCounts = Record<string, number>

export type getPoolResult = PoolData & {
   voteCounts: VoteCounts
   votedAnswerId: string | null
}
```

The error message I'm getting is:

> Type '{ voteCounts: VoteCounts; votedAnswerId: string | null; }' is
> not assignable to type 'getPoolResult'. Type '{ voteCounts:
> VoteCounts; votedAnswerId: string | null; }' is missing the following
> properties from type '{ password?: string | undefined; question:
> string; expiresAt: Date; answers: { value: string; id: string; }[];
> isPublic: boolean; id: string; }': question, expiresAt, answers,
> isPublic, idts(2322)

When i let the typescript infer return i get

```
Promise<{
    pool: {
        voteCounts: VoteCounts;
        votedAnswerId: string | null;
    };
}>
```

Can someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error and how I can resolve it? It seems like there's a mismatch between the returned object and the expected type.

Also, I would like to know if it's possible to use the rest operator `(...)` for the `poolMapper` operation in the return statement, as I would like to include all the properties from the mapped pool object.

Comment: Can you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the problem? Pasting your code over at the [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NdaDym) raises a bunch of errors that are unrelated to the error you're describing.

Comment: hi i find out poolMapper map over Pool class so it inject it functions too like getters and setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the lack of type deduction as it should have been was that the poolMapper mapped by a class which had its own functions in addition to the types I needed.

It was enough to add toPlainObject to the function class